# Change the size of AnalogClock widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, clock

I'm using the builtin AnalogClock widget in my activity layout. I'd like to make it bigger. Adjusting the layout_width and layout_height doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
<AnalogClock
    android:id="@+id/analogClock"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The default Analog clock has dial pad which is of 231 * 231 in HDPI. Even you mention the width and height of the AnalogClock more, these Images are not stretched. To show the AnalogClock bigger, provide your own dial pad and minutes hand and hours hand with custom dimensions.

```
        <AnalogClock
           android:dial="@drawable/your_dial_pad"
           android:hand_hour="@drawable/your_hour_hand"
           android:hand_minute="@drawable/your_minutes_hand"/>
```

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to scale the existing images used for hour, minute, and dial?

Comment: I don't think the default images are exposed outside. Better to for custom images with your own dimensions

Comment: I marked this down because actually you can scale the image.  See the above comment for use of scaleX/scaleY.  However I noticed that wrap_content for width and height doesn't work if you use scaleX so you have  to set the widht/height in dp as well as scale.  Fractional scale worked for me in the above too.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

```
android:scaleX="preferedScale"
```

and

```
 android:scaleY="preferedScale"
```

with `preferedScale` = 1,2,3 ... n

Answer (score 0):

I found that the previous answers didn't work for me. I found a simple solution. Just create your own custom drawable for the clock's background, and set the `android:dial` attribute. You can create your drawable as large as you need. Surely if you want your clock to look pretty you must create two drawables for hours and minutes too. You can simply copy default drawable(s) to somewhere and resize them with an image editor:

```
<AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/AnalogClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dial="@drawable/widgetdial_big"
        android:hand_hour="@drawable/widgethour_big"
        android:hand_minute="@drawable/widgetminute_big" />
```

if you work on a widget, you must declare AppWidgetProviderInfo like this (300dip for example):

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="300dip"
    android:minWidth="300dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0" />
```